# Intrinsic definition in magma

Tags: import, intrinsics, magma-ca

I have been using [Magma](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) for a few weeks now, and all is well except one thing : I can't define my own intrinsics. I have not find that many ressources to learn the language (maybe I can't search...), so I try a lot of things, and right now, I'm stuck on a seemingly simple thing :
I have a file `f.m` that contains the following code :

```
freeze;

a := 1;

function b(n);
  return n+1;
end function;

intrinsic c(n::RngIntElt) -> RngIntElt
{meh}
  return n+1;
end intrinsic;
```

and in the Magma console, in the same folder as this file, I've had the following :

```
> Attach("f.m");
> import "f.m": a,b,c;
> a; 
1
> b(1);
2
> c(1);

>> c(1);
   ^
Runtime error: Symbol 'c' of package "f1.m" not found
```

I really don't understand what I've done wrong, can anyone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some more reading end experimenting, I don't need to import `c` after attaching `f.m`.
intrinsics are automatically loaded. This is an important difference with functions and variables defined in a package file with must be explicitly imported. Since this caused me some trouble, I will still upload this question with the solution.

One picture is worth a thousand words, to make this work, simply enter in the console the following :

```
> Attach("f.m");
> import "f.m": a,b;
> a; 
1
> b(1);
2
> c(1);
2
```

Or in other words, if you don't need the function or the variable, simply don't import anything.